# EZ PUBLISH manually display result

Tags: php, smarty, ezpublish

here's my code

```
{foreach $collection.attributes as $attribute}
{$attribute.contentclass_attribute_name|wash}:
{attribute_result_gui view=info attribute=$attribute}
<br />
{/foreach}
```

what I want is to manually display the result for presentation purposes.

I've tried var_dump `{$collection.attributes|@var_dump}` but only gives me this result `array`.

any idea guys?

thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of ezpublish are you using ?
have you tried {$collection.attributes|attribute(show,2)} ?

Comment: @AmirKoklan here's the version `eZ Publish information: Community Project 2013.5`

Comment: have you tried {$collection.attributes|attribute(show,2)} ?

Comment: @AmirKoklan not yet... what does attribute(show,2) do/works?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{section name=Attribute loop=$collection.attributes}
  {$Attribute:item.contentclass_attribute_name|wash}
  {$Attribute:item.data_text|wash}
{/section}
```

To figure out what variable hold required string try "**|attribute(show,2)**" on any object in ezpublish:

`{$attribute.contentclass_attribute_name|attribute(show,2)}`

Then you will see whichone var is storing it.

This can be helpful:

http://share.ez.no/learn/ez-publish/how-to-create-ez-publish-forms/(page)/4